# Fetching data in the form of Array from Mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am using this function to get the values of all the input tags having name=type1[].

```
var values = $("input[name='type1[]']").map(function(){
                return $(this).val();
              }).get();
              console.log(values);
```

When i console.log this value then i get an array in my console window and then i stores this variable inside my mongodb and when i later fetches it then it automatically gets converted into string.
What i wanna do is to get the variable exactly as an array form.
How can i do that?

Here is my Mongodb code and my ajax request

```
var template = new Temp({
      input_text:req.body.input,
      template_id:ss.user_id
    })

$.ajax({
    url:'./save',
    type:'POST',
    data:'input='+values+'&input1='+values1+'&count='+values1.length,
    success:function(response){}
  });
```

And i am using the middleware bodyparser.json() on my server page maybe because thats why it got converted into string.

Comment: How about you let us see some of your MongoDB code?

Comment: I edited my question thanks